# bind9 load errors

Tags: bind

Getting load errors.  syslogs at the bottom of the post.
If anyone has any suggestions, they are greatly appreciated.

```
sreeve@dcn1:/etc/bind$ cat named.conf.local
    //
    // Do any local configuration here
    //

    // Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
    // organization
    //include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

    zone "dc.org" {
                 type master;
                 file "/etc/bind/db.dc.org";
            };

    zone "28.101.10.in-addr.arpa" {
            type master;
            notify no;
            file "/etc/bind/db.10";
    };

sreeve@dcn1:/etc/bind$ cat db.dc.org
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dcn1.dc.org. root.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      dcn1.dc.org.
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
vsd2            IN      A       10.101.28.30
vcentersso      IN      A       192.168.10.134
xmpp            IN      A       10.101.28.30
_xmpp-client._tcp.xmpp.dc.org. IN SRV 10 0 5222 vsd2.dc.org.
vsc1man         IN      A       10.101.28.32
vsc1            IN      A       10.101.28.32
vrs1            IN      A       192.168.10.150
vrs2            IN      A       192.168.10.151



sreeve@dcn1:/etc/bind$ cat db.10
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dcn1.dc.org. root.localhost. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      dcn1.dc.org.

30      IN      PTR     vsd2.dc.org.
134     IN      PTR     vcentersso.dc.org.
140     IN      PTR     vsc1man.dc.org.
32     IN      PTR     vsc1.dc.org.
150     IN      PTR     vrs1.dc.org.
152     IN      PTR     vrs2.dc.org.
154     IN      PTR     vrs3.dc.org.



Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 658
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone 28.101.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone dc.org/IN: NS 'dcn1.dc.org' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: zone dc.org/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Apr 14 08:54:04 dcn1 named[3738]: all zones loaded
```

Comment: Instead of pictures, post the actual code, that would be more readable and helpful.

Comment: Having trouble with the formatting. Will correct.

Comment: Are... you going to tell us what load errors it's giving you?  Because it looks like you aren't doing that...

Comment: Please use code formatting, not mixes of bold/not-bold for your zone files - it's more readable this way.  You also need to tell us what errors you're actually getting when loading `bind` - as it stands the question is unclear.

Comment: Hopefully I've got the formatting done properly.  If you have any suggestions, it would be great.  Thanks.